# Cannot access Authentication section in Firebase Console

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-console

Can anyone access the Authentication tab and see the expected Authentication admin console in Firebase console?

When I navigate to: [https://console.firebase.google.com/project/{my-project-id}/authentication](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/%7Bmy-project-id%7D/authentication)
I see it flash to the expected screen, where it has the tabs under the header `Authentication`.

The tabs are `Sign-in method`, `Templates`, `Usage`, and I think `settings`. I really do not see this section and I feel like it must be a bug. I have yet to start on any auth stuff for my app until this morning, and just never noticed the section flicker like it has been.

If anyone can access their authentication section, or if anyone knows how to get there through a different route (or in the Google Cloud console instead) that is what I am looking for!

---

Edit: 11:53 US GMT 10/23/2023

Looked in the console and saw a 404 is returned.

> error Object { code: 404, message: "CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND", status: "NOT_FOUND" }

Strange. It hits two routes (notice the bold **admin** in the second link):

- [https://identitytoolkit.clients6.google.com/v2/projects/{project-name}/config?alt=json&key={an-alpha-numeric-key}](https://identitytoolkit.clients6.google.com/v2/projects/%7Bproject-name%7D/config?alt=json&key=%7Ban-alpha-numeric-key%7D)
- [https://identitytoolkit.clients6.google.com/**admin**/v2/projects/{project-name}/config?alt=json&key={an-alpha-numeric-key}](https://identitytoolkit.clients6.google.com/**admin**/v2/projects/%7Bproject-name%7D/config?alt=json&key=%7Ban-alpha-numeric-key%7D)

The first route is hit once and fails with the error above, the second route is hit 3 times and fails with the exact same message.

---

Note: I have tried the route: [https://console.firebase.google.com/project/{my-project-id}/authentication/settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/%7Bmy-project-id%7D/authentication/settings) (and I've tried usage and templates). Same flickering happens where the site shows the correct looking console and then switches to the "get started" authentication page.

Below is a GIF demonstrating the problem.

[image: GIF of issue on my broswer]

I have tried multiple browsers: Firefox, Safari, and Chromium.

*Note: I am not in a big rush, but would love to know if anyone else has experienced this.*

Comment: Hmm... that looks off indeed. I just tried on a few of my own projects (both older and newer) and can access the auth panel in the console without problems. Is there any relevant error message showing in the developer panel or network panel of the browser when this happens?

Comment: Yes, I get an error, I'll update the question. Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I'm not sure why, but when I clicked on `Get Started!` it randomly flickered and opened up the Authentication section as expected. Now when I enter the Authentication section, the Authentication console shows correctly and I can do all the admin stuff I wanted to.

Previously, I do remember clicking the `Get started!` button just opened the documentation for the auth stuff, like how to use the UI package and what to do with the SDK, but after about a day or two I just clicked it again and it worked.